# ddply generating dataframe not separated by levels

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

Hi I have what is probably a very simple problem but I cannot figure it out. I am using ddply to create a dataframe to be used in ggplot2.

Here is my data truncated:

```
Subject Group   Day gkg Strain
PE4 E   1   0.829556075 P
PE5 E   1   0.871823204 P
PE6 E   1   1.135461255 P
PS4 S   1   3.316062176 P
PS5 S   1   2.61627907  P
PS6 S   1   3.286004057 P
WE4 E   1   0.154101563 W
WE6 E   1   1.317852495 W
WS4 S   1   2.007434944 W
WS5 S   1   1.28        W
PE4 E   2   0.642209302 P
PE5 E   2   0.502644788 P
PE6 E   2   1.319834559 P
PS4 S   2   3.350515464 P
PS5 S   2   2.994241843 P
PS6 S   2   3.507014028 P
WE4 E   2   0.109366337 W
WE5 E   2   0.493125    W
WE6 E   2   0.721960784 W
WS4 S   2   2.542056075 W
WS5 S   2   1.23752495  W
```

I created a subset of this data based on group E or S

```
Edata = which(data$Group == "E")
e = data[Edata,]
Sdata = which(data$Group == "S")
s= data[Sdata,]
```

Then I tried to use ddply to create a data frame including the mean, standard deviation an standard error of the mean

```
newdataIntakeEGKG = ddply(e, .(e$Strain, e$Day), summarise,
    N = sum(!is.na(e$gkg)),
    mean = mean(e$gkg, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(e$gkg, na.rm = TRUE),
    se = sd(e$gkg, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(e$gkg))))
```

This generates the following output:

```
e$Strain e$Day  N     mean        sd         se
1         P     1 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
2         P     2 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
3         P     3 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
4         P     4 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
5        W     1 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
6        W     2 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
7        W     3 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
8        W     4 60 0.630856 0.3593886 0.04639687
```

When I calculated by hand I learned its taking the mean of both Strains combined. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want all the `e$` in your ddply call. See if this works.

```
ddply(e, .(Strain, Day), summarise,
      N=sum(!is.na(gkg)),
      mean=mean(gkg, na.rm=TRUE),
      sd=sd(gkg, na.rm=TRUE),
      se=sd(gkg, na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(gkg))))
```

---

A slightly cleaner alternative, although it may not necessarily give the same results:

```
ddply(na.omit(e), .(Strain, Day), summarise,
      N=length(gkg), mean=mean(gkg), sd=sd(gkg), se=sd(gkg)/length(gkg))
```

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! do I not need `e$` because I specify the dataset with `(e,..)`?

Comment: Yep, that's right. In fact, by specifying `e$` you're confusing ddply: it's computing the means and SD's based on the entire data frame `e`, rather than the subsets defined by your grouping variables.